# spring JDBC Template: fetching jdbc connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I use Spring Jdbc template to acquire database Connection.
here is my dispatcher.xml config

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.cloudera.impala.jdbc4.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:impala://IP:Port/DatabaseName;auth=noSasl" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="50000" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
        <property name="jmxEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnConnect" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/> 
</bean>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

and i use jdbcTemplate for executing my query as autowird Object as well as NamedParameterJdbcTemplate via new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource)

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

while fetching JDBC Connection it takes too long or fails some times, should i use an autowired object for "NamedParameterJdbcTemplate" Object, i dont know where the connection leaks occure.

Thanks, 
Siva

Comment: You probably should, no reason not to, but it's not going to change anything. Your problems are caused by something else. How do you know that it takes too long? Maybe it takes as much time as it should?

Comment: each query execution takes more than usual time or fails sometimes to fetch connection, execute a query and return connection to connection pooling. if my code does not has any problem, will it be the network issue

Comment: Sure, might be network issue or one of your components can't handle the load.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, let me check my network connectivity. it shall be the database issue too right or shall I check with a different data source such as HikariCP instead of apache datasource.

Comment: I would suggest to try with local db and see if query time is same.

Comment: let me check with that scenario and when I try with DB Installed in another IP, sometimes the broken pipeline error throws.